# Improving Website Performance

Tags: javascript, performance, web

I am working on an application in which there are 10 pages. Once I successfully login into the application, each of these 10 pages are loaded in separate iframes. And all these 10 pages make use of 5 JavaScript files.

Currently I am downloading these 5 js files on each page load. I want to improve my application performance. And I know that minifying  no of HTTP requests will improve performance.

So rather than downloading scripts in each page, Is it better to download these 5 JavaScript files only once at the top(after login) and make use of the scripts in each page which has been already loaded at the top by passing the window reference. Is it the correct approach? Is there any disadvantage of using this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is a good approach and will make your site fast.

If you will include the js or css file from the other site then it will take time to load and your site will be low in performance.

There can be cons of including the files from other site is if refer site removed those files then your site will not work and this will affect the functionality of your site.

> So it is good practice to use the files from your project folders and
>   path. So download it and then use them

Comment: One of the other cons is that you will have to update the libraries (if you are using any) manually. I.e. you include jQuery 1.8 as a file on your server, but you need functionality from 1.9 - you'd have to manually redownload and update. But I guess that's small beans.

Comment: @Neurofluxation you are right. But in that case user need to update the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

In general you want to put the Javascript files at the bottom of the page (assuming you don't need them at the top to generate something such as using `document.write`) so that your page can load fast and then the page can load the necessary Javascript.

You can also consider combining the js files into one that is minified. This is a double edged sword though because it makes debugging very hard but it does reduce the number of HTTP request your application needs to make. However, in general, reducing the number of files you have is a great start to improving performance.

Overall though you should not need to worry that much about performance especially among different pages. Once the js files are loaded, the browser will cache it so it can be accessed again quickly.

Comment: I will put my scripts at the bottom of the page itself. I meant by the statement "download these 5 JavaScript files only once at the top and make use of the files" that, In my application once I login I open each page in an iframe. So is it better to load the script only once after login and make use of those scripts in each page which has already been loaded in the top by passing the window reference.